# WPF C# how to bind values defined in AppStrings.resx to XAML Content

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

Um trying to access a value defined in the AppStrings.resx As follows but it is not working , how may I access a value defined directly ?

```
             xmlns:Resources="clr-namespace:VApp.Wpf.Properties"
             Content="{Binding Resources.AppStrings.Delete_Button_Content}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the generated code for resource (.resx) file you will see that the class in there is `static`. So you should be binding those resources using `x:Static`.

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Static Resources:AppStrings.Delete_Button_Content}" />
```